# Wordpress database with newer code

Tags: wordpress

I have my wordpress code version at 3.9.2 with plugins updates and a wordpress 3.4.2 database . If i configure my old database with the code and run the site , the database will be update with the 3.9.2 changes automatically ? or i have to rollback my code to 3.4.2 and start the upgrade again ? tks!